# REG_BINARY and python

Tags: python, winreg

I want to write value into subkey in python, with other data types everything going well, except REG_BINARY. Is it possible to change value of REG_BINARY with winreg? I can't figure out how to do that. I use value stored as string, but I receive "Objects of type 'str' can not be used as binary registry values". How to use that value as binary?